# pass arguments from client side to server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik

I have two comboboxes and would like pass selected value and text to the server method (RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs) when the first combobox selected index changed.

Here is my code. But I am getting Javascript error message at this line. `RadComboBox2.requestItems(item, false)`. Thanks for the help.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox 
        ID="RadComboBox1" 
        runat="server" 
        OnClientSelectedIndexChanging="LoadNames"
        OnItemsRequested="RadComboBox1_ItemsRequested" 
/>
<telerik:RadComboBox 
        ID="RadComboBox2" 
        runat="server" 
        AllowCustomText="true"                    
        OnItemsRequested="RadComboBox2_ItemsRequested" 
/>
```

.

```
    function LoadNames(combo, eventArqs)
    {
        var item = eventArqs.get_item();
        var RadComboBox2= $find('<%= RadComboBox2.ClientID %>');
        RadComboBox2.requestItems(item, false);
    }

    protected void RadComboBox2_ItemsRequested(object o, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
          // I want first combobox text and value here
            LoadNames(e.Text, e.Value);
    }
```

Comment: what is the error that you're getting?

Comment: item is not valid object error

Comment: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Is the line before the RadComboBox2.requestItems(...) returning the correct thing?  I'm guessing it's not returning what you expect.

Comment: yes. I can see item.get_text() and item.get_value().

Answer (score 0):

`item` is supposed to be a string, not an object, try using
 `item.get_text()`
 or `item.get_value()`

on the server side you can get that string http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/combobox/combo_client_model.html

Comment: Can't I pass both of them? I need both values.